# Animation duration does not work

Tags: android, animation, android-custom-view, ondraw, drawrectangle

I'm creating a custom view which is basically a Rectangle (RectF object). I would like that according to a specified value by the user, to change the rectangle size accordingly with animation. So I've tried that:

```
public class ObjectView extends View {

public int mCanvasWidth;
public int mCanvasHeight;

public int mVolumeHeight = 0;

public RectF mObjectHead;
public RectF mObjectBody;
public RectF mObjectBodyVolume;
public Canvas mCanvas;

private boolean mInitDone = false;

public ObjectView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ObjectView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void init()
{

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.mCanvas = canvas;
    float objectHeadDistanceFromLeft = mCanvasWidth / 3;
    float objectHeadWidth = mCanvasWidth / 3;

    float objectBodyDistanceFromTop = mCanvasHeight / 5;
    float objectHeadHeight = mCanvasHeight / 5;
    mBatteryHead = new RectF(batteryHeadDistanceFromLeft,0,2*objectHeadWidth,objectHeadHeight+5);
    Paint objectHeadPaint = new Paint();
    objectHeadPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.batifyColor));
    canvas.drawRect(mObjectHead,objectHeadPaint);

    mObjectBody = new RectF(0,(int)objetBodyDistanceFromTop,mCanvasWidth,mCanvasHeight);
    Paint objectBodyPaint = new Paint();
    objectBodyPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    objectBodyPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.batifyColor));
    objectBodyPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    canvas.drawRect(mObjectBody,objectBodyPaint);

    mObjectBodyVolume = new RectRectF(12, (int) objectBodyDistanceFromTop + 10, mCanvasWidth - 12, mVolumeHeight);
    Paint volumeBodyPaint = new Paint();
    volumeBodyPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.batifyColor));
    canvas.drawRect(mObjectBodyVolume, volumeBodyPaint);

}


public void setStateOnObject(){
    this.mVolumeHeight = mCanvasHeight;
    ObjectAnimator animateBottom = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mObjectBodyVolume, "bottom", mObjectBodyVolume.bottom, this.mVolumeHeight);
    animateBottom.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            postInvalidate();
        }
    });
    AnimatorSet rectAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
    rectAnimation.play(animateBottom);
    rectAnimation.setDuration(10000).start();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    mCanvasWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    mCanvasHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
}
 }
```

The problem is that the size is not updating progressively as expected but directly to the final value whatever the duration time of the animation. 
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I created a sample and tried the same and it works as expected.

Comment: It's updating progressively ?

Comment: yes. i can see the animation update slowly.

Comment: Did you change something ?

Comment: I never do the allocation in onDraw. Only draw part is left there. The rest is the same. You don't want allocations and initialization on every refresh

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course you're right. I've removed the allocations and initialization form the onDraw method and placed in the init. Now I'm getting this message: ***Method setBottom() with type float not found on target class class android.graphics.RectF***. And it's true that RectF does not have such method..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126501/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-hubert-solecki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid allocation and calculations in `onDraw` for the sake of performance

The property bottom requires a setter. `RectF` does not have one. So have this

```
public class AnimatableRectF extends RectF{


    public AnimatableRectF(float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
        super(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    public AnimatableRectF(RectF r) {
        super(r);
    }

    public AnimatableRectF(Rect r) {
        super(r);
    }

    public void setTop(float top){
        this.top = top;
    }
    public void setBottom(float bottom){

        this.bottom = bottom;
    }
    public void setRight(float right){
        this.right = right;
    }
    public void setLeft(float left){
        this.left = left;
    }

}
```

Then

```
 mObjectBodyVolume = new AnimatableRectF(12, (int) objectBodyDistanceFromTop + 10, mCanvasWidth - 12, mVolumeHeight);
```

The animation part remains the same